# How to optimize the facebook likes counter onpage

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm trying to optimize my following code that shows how many likes the page/post on my website have.
This code is looping for 20 posts in my homepage and it's very slow to load.
Is there a way to speed up this code maybe using another call?

Thanks

```
$url =  get_permalink();
$fburl = "http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?  query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url='$url'&format=atom";
$ch = curl_init($fburl);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$atom_data = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match('#like_count>(\d+)<#',$atom_data,$matches);
$like_count = $matches[1]; 
echo "$like_count";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use an `IN` list for your URLs like this:

```
select url, like_count from link_stat where url in ('URL1', 'URL2')
```

Questions:

- Why do you use a deprecated endpoint, and not `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=...`
- Why don't you use JSON formatting? This can easily be parsed with PHP and you don't have to use `preg_match`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'ma newbie of JSON, so I'm not able to use graph.facebook.com but I'm reading that is the best method. I think I have to study a little bit...

Comment: In the end JSON is also only text and you could use your RegExp with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up your code by using batched requests. So you request just one time and not 20 times... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/